# Proving limit of the sequence ${ x }_{ n+1 }=\frac { 1 }{ 3 } \left( 2{ x }_{ n }+\frac { a }{ { x }_{ n }^{ 2 } } \right) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Here is the question I should prove.

> Given:  $${ x }_{ n+1 }=\frac { 1 }{ 3 } \left( 2{ x }_{ n }+\frac { a }{ { x }_{ n } ^{ 2 } }  \right),{ x }_{ 0 }>0, n \epsilon  \mathbb{N}   $$ prove that $$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ x_{ n } } =\sqrt [ 3 ]{ a } $$

Firstly ,I tried to show the sequence is monotone and bounded.

**Edited**:$$\\ { x }_{ n+1 }=\frac { 1 }{ 3 } \left( 2{ x }_{ n }+\frac { a }{ { x }_{ n }^{ 2 } }  \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 3 } \left( { x }_{ n }+{ x }_{ n }+\frac { a }{ { x }_{ n }^{ 2 } }  \right) \ge \sqrt [ 3 ]{ a } $$
 so $${ x }_{ n }\ge \sqrt [ 3 ]{ a } ,(n\ge 2)$$ 
and from the given condition we can write it as follows: $${ x }_{ n+1 }-{ x }_{ n }=\frac { a-{ x }_{ n }^{ 3 } }{ 3{ x }_{ n }^{ 2 } } <0\\ { x }_{ n+1 }<{ x }_{ n }$$
as the result sequence is monotone and bounded so the it has a limit point.Now let say $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { x }_{ n }=s } \quad $ then $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { x }_{ n+1 }=s } $ so $s=\frac { 1 }{ 3 } \left( 2s+\frac { a }{ { s }^{ 2 } }  \right) \Rightarrow { 3s }^{ 3 }=2{ s }^{ 3 }+a\Rightarrow s=\sqrt [ 3 ]{ a } $
 I would like to know is proof is right or missed something,thanks in advance!

Comment: This part $\frac { 1 }{ 3 } \left( 2{ x }_{ n }^{ 2 }+\frac { a }{ { x }_{ n }^{ 2 } }  \right) <\frac { 2 }{ 3 } \sqrt { 2{ x }_{ n }^{ 2 }\cdot \frac { a }{ { x }_{ n }^{ 2 } }  }$ is wrong. It should be $\frac { 1 }{ 3 } \left( 2{ x }_{ n }^{ 2 }+\frac { a }{ { x }_{ n }^{ 2 } }  \right) \ge\frac { 2 }{ 3 } \sqrt { 2{ x }_{ n }^{ 2 }\cdot \frac { a }{ { x }_{ n }^{ 2 } }  }$ since $a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequence is decreasing, so you should provide a lower bound not a upper bound. The rest part is correct I think.

Just a hint:

$$2x_n+\frac{a}{x_n^2}=x_n+x_n+\frac{a}{x_n^2}$$

then you can apply the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, if $a\geq 0$.